# How to run a React Native App with Node js Backend on Android Device?

Tags: android, node.js, reactjs, api

I want to run my React Native app on my local Android Device. The app uses Node js APIs for fetching data from mysql. The problem is, my android device can't access node js app which results in no data. The app works fine on Android Emulator on using address 10.0.2.2 but can't access this on Android Device
P.S The node js APIs are o local server (localhost:3000)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So I solved it like this. 
1. I got my **ip address** from cmd using ipconfig
2. In node js, I wrote the server listening code like this

```
const hostname = "192.168.2.103";
const port = "3002";
app.listen(port, hostname, () => {
    console.log(`Server running at http://${hostname}:${port}/`);
});
```

Now the app will run on this ip address instead of localhost and hence we can access it anywhere on the same network even in **React Native fetching from APIs process**

Answer (score 1):

You have to set your API Address in android device by using `adb reverse`.

for example, if your APIs is on `localhost:3000`, run this command:

```
$ adb reverse tcp:3000 tcp:3000
```

Now when your phone tries to request to `localhost:3000` it will routed to that address in your laptop.

Don't forget to recompile your app after running that command.

Reference & more info:

1. https://blog.grio.com/2015/07/android-tip-adb-reverse.html
2. https://www.jaygould.co.uk/2018-11-07-react-native-connecting-development-server-debugging/

Answer (score 0):

That is because when you run your React Native app on a phone you are not on your computer anymore, hence, localhost (your computer) is not accesible anymore. Try using a full ip address, even  in a local environment.

Let's say you attack your api using axios to localhost:3000, you should change this localhost for the ip of your computer. Then it should work.

Comment: I tried this already. it works for php localhost but not helping in node js server

Answer (score 0):

> **Connect your mobile device to the same network as your machine**.

Then try this command :

```
ifconfig
```

Find your machine's ip address from the log. You'll find something like this :

```
en0: flags=8863<UP,BROADCAST,SMART,RUNNING,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> mtu 1500
    options=400<CHANNEL_IO>
    ether a4:83:e7:d5:35:85 
    inet6 fe80::439:b3fe:c51a:364%en0 prefixlen 64 secured scopeid 0x6 
    inet 192.168.1.6 netmask 0xffffff00 broadcast 192.168.1.255
    nd6 options=201<PERFORMNUD,DAD>
    media: autoselect
    status: active
```

Get the address, which is this in my case : `inet 192.168.1.6`.

On your app, input this address for hitting the node service. `192.168.1.6`.
If node is running on `port 3000`, add directly to the address.
`192.168.1.6:3000`

Comment: I did this. it works for php localhost but not helping in node js server