# How to run a node script through react native

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, react-native

I have created a node file that sends an OTP SMS. When the user clicks on a button in their react native app, the node file should run to generate and send the OTP message. Im not sure how to trigger that. Any idea?

Comment: Did you see this [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61122428/how-to-run-a-react-native-app-with-node-js-backend-on-android-device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61122428/how-to-run-a-react-native-app-with-node-js-backend-on-android-device) ??